# Converting base64 data from json response into ms excel file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen SO questions similar to my use case w/ angular and other server side platforms but not for pure javascript.

I have an app where I do a $.ajax and do a get call to an API, which returns a previously converted excel file (excel to base64); I need to re-convert this base64 data back into it's original form - i.e. into Excel file. I tried retracing the steps I took to convert the excel into base64, reversing some of them, but I'm not able to generate the original file. An excel file IS being generated, but it still has base64 data and therefore opens w/ errors and in a corrupted state. 
Has anyone else successfully done this?

Below is my code and fiddle link: (I didn't add the base64 json data (responseData) here since it's large, but it's on the fiddle)

```
var bindata = window.atob(responseData);
function DownloadExcel() {
  window.location.href = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64, bindata"
}
var blob = new Blob([responseData], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob);
}
else {
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(objectUrl);
}
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/damon_matt/2ofz6xrd/

Comment: Ah and after better reading your question, you need to `...base64," + bindata` not `...base64, bindata`

Comment: @Kaiido - you mean another js function to convert base64? I'm not following you...

Comment: @RogerDodger If you do, literally, what Kaiido said, your problem should be solved.

Comment: Ismael - I have NO CLUE what he means by " you need to ...base64," + bindata not ...base64, bindata" in the comment above. What is he talking about?

Comment: This is the code I currently have (posted above and also in fiddle): var bindata = window.atob(responseData);
function DownloadExcel() {
window.location.href = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64, bindata"
}
             var blob = new Blob([bindata], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
              if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                  window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob);
              }
              else {
                  var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  window.open(objectUrl);
              }

Comment: Removed the atob() function and tried this way but still not able to do the excel conversion:  var blob = new Blob([responseData], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
              if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                  window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob);
              }
              else {
                  var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  window.open(objectUrl);
              }

Comment: Tried it this way, download.xls is created but still get the error download and file format do not match - could that be because the original file was .xlsx?

Comment: ... I don't have a jsfiddle account so can't create such a long snippet, but what I meant is that in your `DownloadExcel` function, you are setting the page's href literally to `"data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64, bindata"`, what you want is `window.location.href = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64," + responseData`, so that the data be part of this href. Forget about the Blob for now.

Comment: I remember trying that without success; let me give it another whirl - will report back. thx

Comment: No that doesn't work either - it displays the EXACT same error that is generated with my code: "the file format and extension don't match" - the original excel file had a .xlsx extension - could that have anything to do with it?